# DebugView Crashes on Remote Connection

Tags: debugging, debugview

I am attempting to connect to a remote computer running DebugView (on Windows Server 2022). After configuring the remote computer firewall to allow DebugView. I am running DebugView on the remote machine with:
`dbgview64.exe /a /t /g`

Locally I am running the same version of DebugView (4.90) (Windows 11). I choose Computer | Connect and enter the IP Address of the remote computer. After a few moments I see the remote computer report "Connected" and I get the same in the local UI.

Then the local instance of DebugView crashes without any error message.

I have tried setting the local history depth to 10 to see if it's the size of the log but it crashes just the same.

Comment: You are not alone. I'm having this exact issue with 4.90 myself, but if I swap roles of the agent and viewer to the reverse, it works fine. This does not help other than to drive me nuts because I can't find a reason why it works in the direction that doesn't help me but not in the correct direction.
Did you find a solution?